# ByteBuffer as static final fields within classes

Tags: java

I have certain values for columns that are frequently required to be stored in DB. Previously, I had been caching those values as `static final byte[]` class fields but unfortunately `byte[]` doesnt allow for easier equality comparasions(to check if another byte array elements are just the same as this one) thus I am thinking of using `static final ByteBuffer` class fields  as that would allow me for easier equality comparisions *(my DB anyway requires to convert all values to ByteBuffer for writes)*.

Now since I am new to ByteBuffer usage, I just wanted to ask if there are any issues with a few (<100) `static final ByteBuffer` fields within my classes each containing a byte[] of length 2?

Comment: Why not simply use a byte[] and then `java.util.Arrays.equals(byte[] a, byte[] b)`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question: why do your cached bytes need to be `static`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Actually I am using an API that does the equality comparasion, so I cannot make it working

Comment: @DanielPryden: static because they are just same anytime & not different for different instances

Answer (score 0):

What sort of issues are you worried about? Buffers are not threadsafe... but it's unclear what your usage needs are so that may or may not be an issue. The source code to ByteBuffer (and all of the buffers) is available for you to look at.. at the end of the day it's a `final byte[]` with some sugar on top.