# Can ByteBuffers be used as 'long living' static objects?

Tags: java

I need to store certain ByteBuffer objects as static fields in my classes. Are there any concerns about storing them as long living objects or should I create them on demand? I frequently need access to those objects.

Comment: Are you likely to have a similar number in use at any time?  If so, have you considered a pool?

Comment: Actually these are just static final constants that are required for application self needs..

Answer (score 1):

Buffers are not thread safe.so if it is a multi threaded application, you need to take special care about it. There is a similar discussion here:

[ByteBuffer as static final fields within classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051531/bytebuffer-as-static-final-fields-within-classes)

If that is the case my suggestion is create it dynamically as it will help you to allocate the memory only for the required data for the operation.If you pool it and the data going to be read is less than allocated, then unnecessary memory will be allocated.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not particularly worried about the memory footprint as these are just 4 byte integers converted to ByteBuffers.

Comment: @user, so my suggestion is to construct dynamically as I do not think it is going to be any performance burden.